# SQL REPLACE INTO not working

Tags: mysql, insert, replace

So I have a form that can get data from a database by its ID (auto-incremented column(Primary Key)) and display all fields in the `<input>` tags via value properties. And when I submit the form I want it to either INSERT a new row if the ID from the ID column doesn't already exist and if it does I want to UPDATE the rest of the data in the row with the same ID.

I have been trying to research this, but no one seems to be doing the same thing I am trying to do, its always slightly different. I found a REPLACE INTO and created it like below:

```
$sqlString = 'REPLACE INTO coursework
SET cwID=`'. $cwID .'`,
cwTitle=`'. $cwTitle .'`,
cwContent=`'. $cwContent .'`,
cwProgress=`'. $cwProgress .'`,
cwDue=`'. $cwDue .'`;
```

All the $cw[] variables being content received from $_POST method.

I keep getting a *Error code: 1054-Unknown column '6' in 'field list'* - 
the "Unknown column '6'" is mysql trying to call $cwID (value of $_POST['cwID']) instead of the cwID column(which is the Primary Key for my table). I feel like there is something simple and stupid I am missing but I have never used this REPLACE INTO method before.

I saw a post about `INSERT IGNORE INTO` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but both of those sound more destructive than what I am looking for.

I just want to make sure that the table is updated if the cwID exists and the auto-increment is kept in tact, or a new row is added if there is no ID. Should I just run a SELECT query to see if it exists and INSERT/ UPDATE appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the backticks with single quotes:

```
$sqlString = 
 "REPLACE INTO coursework SET cwID='$cwID', cwTitle='$cwTitle', cwContent='$cwContent', cwProgress='$cwProgress', cwDue='$cwDue'";
```

Also, note that `"` will interpolate your variables.

Comment: leepowers for some reason that does not work for me, it just keeps adding new rows to the db.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Remove</strike> Replace the back-ticks (`) surrounding the strings with single quotes (').

MySql is trying to find a column named by the strings you are using as values.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Comment: I tried that, but it messes up the query even more.
`Error code: 1064-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Android 02), cwContent=
Read and study Chapters 5-6 in \"Learning Android' at line 3`

Comment: @jbingman Try escaping the post data via `mysql_real_escape_string`. If that doesn't help log the sql statement and post it. Back-ticks are not going to help.